# Divide two rows over Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have a table like this :

```
Id Sym sum_amount pair 
11  2    1000      1
11  3     500      1
22  4    200       2
22  4    50        2
```

And I would like to divide one value in a pair in the second in the same pair over partition by Id, Sym.

and get those results:

```
Id Sym sum_amount pair Div
11  2    1000      1    2
11  3    500       1   0.5
22  4    200       2    4
22  4    50        2   0.25
```

I think I will need something like this:

```
Ratio[???](Sum_Amount) Over (Partition by Id, Sym, pair)
```

Any way to do this? I know that can I average over the pair, sum etc but I don't know how can I do those ratios? are there a built in function for ratio?

Thanks.

Comment: Still not clear. What do you want to divide by what?

Comment: Hmm, i think the penny dropped. What if there are more than two? Is the sample data wrong? I think `11  3` should be `11  2` to get same values as the first row.

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . The column name is called "pair", so I think it is fair to assume that there are two of them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: if it's always a pair it would be better to store them in one row in  a separate column. Makes everything easier and is safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm.  You need the *other* value for the division.  One method is to get the `min()` and `max()` and choose the *other* one:

```
select id, sum, sum_amount, pair,
       (case when max(sum_amount) over (partition by pair) = sum_amount
             then sum_amount / min(sum_amount) over (partition by pair)
             else sum_amount / max(sum_amount) over (partition by pair)
        end) as div
from t;
```

Comment: Integer division prevents correct results and `sum` is `sym`. I think also it should be `Partition by Id, Sym, pair`.

Comment: @Jordan . . . If `sum_amount` is an integer, then multiply by 1.0 or convert to an appropriate decimal type.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Gordon's approach but using a CTE, avoiding integer division and including all three columns as desired (i guess `Sym=3` was a typo in your sample data):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select id, Sym, sum_amount, pair, 
           minAmount = min(sum_amount) over (partition by Id, Sym, pair),
           maxAmount = max(sum_amount) over (partition by Id, Sym, pair),
           rMin = 1.0 * sum_amount / min(sum_amount) over (partition by Id, Sym, pair),
           rMax = 1.0 * sum_amount / max(sum_amount) over (partition by Id, Sym, pair)
   FROM t
)
SELECT id, Sym, sum_amount, pair,
       Div = CASE WHEN sum_amount = maxAmount THEN rMin ELSE rMax END
FROM CTE;
```

<kbd>[sql-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d8b4/2/0)</kbd>